# Creating 2 sql tables upon run in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm a newbie in JDBC and I'm trying to make trial program in which the program itself will create a database and 2 tables in it. However, it always end up with only 1 table inside the database.

```
Connection con = null;
    Connection con1 = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    Statement statement1 = null;
    try{
        //Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost", "root", "");
        con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost", "root", "");
        
        statement = con.createStatement();
        statement1 = con1.createStatement();
        
        String sql = "create database user";
        statement.execute(sql);
        statement.execute("use user");
        String firstTable = "create table login" + "(username varchar(255) not null primary key,"
                + "password varchar(255) not null" + ")";
        statement.execute(firstTable);
        
        statement1.execute("create table userInfo" + 
                "(ID int not null,"
                + "firstName varchar(255) not null,"
                + "lastName varchar (255) not null,"
                + "middle varchar(255),"
                + "birth_Date varchar(255) not null,"
                + "gender varchar(6) not null,"
                + "e_Mail varchar(255) not null,"
                + "c_Group varchar(255) not null,"
                + "position varchar(255) not null" + ")");
        
    }
    catch(SQLException w){

    }
    finally{
        con.close();
        con1.close();
    }
```

I also tried it with only one statement and con like this but it didn't work as well

```
Connection con = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    try{
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost", "root", "");
        statement = con.createStatement();
        
        String sql = "create database user";
        statement.execute(sql);
        statement.execute("use user");
        statement.executeUpdate("create table login" + "(username varchar(255) not null primary key,"
                + "password varchar(255) not null" + ")");
        
        statement.executeUpdate("create table userInfo" + 
                "(ID int not null,"
                + "firstName varchar(255) not null,"
                + "lastName varchar (255) not null,"
                + "middle varchar(255),"
                + "birth_Date varchar(255) not null,"
                + "gender varchar(6) not null,"
                + "e_Mail varchar(255) not null,"
                + "c_Group varchar(255) not null,"
                + "position varchar(255) not null)");
        con.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException w){

    }
finally{
con.close()
}
```

Comment: `executeUpdate` is for INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements according to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)). Have you tried just using `execute`?

Comment: .Yes. I tried it as well but it still creates only 1 table.

Comment: Side note: an empty `catch` block is useless. At least put a print statement in there. How do you know an exception is not thrown?

Comment: Johnny Mopp thank you Sir. I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestion of printing something on catch block [Johnny Mopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669576/johnny-mopp) I found why am I not getting my desired outcome and where is the fault.
I'm not sure if this is the proper way but I did it like this:

```
Connection con = null;
    Connection con1 = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    Statement statement1 = null;
    try{
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost", "root", "");
        
        statement = con.createStatement();
        
        String sql = "create database user";
        statement.execute(sql);
        statement.execute("use user");
        String firstTable = "create table login" + "(username varchar(255) not null primary key,"
                + "password varchar(255) not null" + ")";
        statement.execute(firstTable);
        
        con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/user", "root", "");
        statement1 = con1.createStatement();
        statement1.execute("create table userInfo" + 
                "(ID int not null,"
                + "firstName varchar(255) not null,"
                + "lastName varchar (255) not null,"
                + "middle varchar(255),"
                + "birth_Date varchar(255) not null,"
                + "gender varchar(6) not null,"
                + "e_Mail varchar(255) not null,"
                + "c_Group varchar(255) not null,"
                + "position varchar(255) not null" + ")");
        
    }
    catch(SQLException w){
        w.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        con.close();
        con1.close();
    }
```

thank you as well [tnw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/770270/tnw)